# CUDA Block-level Shared Registers

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

Is there any way that I can use the `registers` such that are visible for a warp/block of threads to access, just like the `shared memory`?

One more assumption is that I already have the size for each warp/block, for example, I need `64xsizeof(float)` registers.

The major reason for this is that I found the random access from a warp to shared memory is very slow in the case of non-coalesced access required by the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, no.

1. You have no mechanism to force or direct the compiler to place items in registers.  For example the C++ `register` keyword does not do this.  Register usage is under control of the compiler.
2. Even if you could, registers are not "shared" the way shared memory is or can be, visible to multiple threads in the warp/threadblock.  Registers, once allocated to the thread that owns them, are visible that thread only.  They cannot become visible to any other thread in the warp or threadblock.

If you simply had a need for per-thread local storage, that is not shared among threads, and your usage met a number of other requirements, you might be able to "coax" the compiler into placing those items in registers. [This forum thread](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvcc-ptxas-under-utilizing-registers-for-arrays/38071) offers an example on how it may be done, and what it looks like.  Again, once the compiler sees its way clear to do so, and decides that there is good reason to do so (i.e. a "belief" of possible performance improvement) the compiler will automatically place items in registers.  You don't have direct control over it.

Comment: Is it possible to embed some PTX assembly in my CUDA code?
For example, at the beginning of each warp.

Allocate a set of registers for each block/warp;
Each thread would use these registers based on their thread laneid (i.e., each thread will know which register it will read and write).
Any suggestion or recommendation on this?

Comment: Sure, you can [embed PTX assembly in CUDA code](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/inline-ptx-assembly/index.html).  There are many examples here on the `cuda` tag of doing so.  But it doesn't change anything in this answer.  PTX is not something that forces the compiler to use registers in a certain way.  Actual register usage is determined by the `ptxas` tool, which takes PTX and converts it to SASS, the actual code that runs on a GPU.  And `ptxas` is an *optimizing compiler*, not simply an assembler.  Furthermore, PTX doesn't allow registers to be shared between threads.

Comment: Ok, I see, I am wondering whether the case in `wmma::fragment` for Tensor Core computation, where all registers from a warps of threads build this fragment, How could I know which register I access from each thread? for example, in thread, when I call `a_frag.x[t]`.

Comment: There is no way to know a-priori which registers will be used. (You could, of course, inspect the resultant SASS with the binary utilities.) Furthermore, loading a fragment doesn't change any of the things I mentioned.  The registers are not shared between threads in a warp.  The fragment is effectively a set of registers per thread in the warp.  No thread in the warp has access to the whole fragment (once loaded).  It only has access to its own section of the fragment.

Comment: so there is no way to know the mapping of a_frag.x[t] --> index of element in the fragment?

Comment: I said there was no way to know a-priori which *registers* will be used in each thread.   We are very far afield from your question now.  If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Comment: @Daniel Quoting the official programming guide: `The mapping of matrix elements into fragment internal storage is unspecified and subject to change in future architectures. `

Comment: @AbatorAbetor, got it, Thanks!

Comment: BTW Registers can be sometimes used like a (thread-local) array by using the preprocessor to generate varable names. E.g. Boost preprocessor for FOR-Loops and index calculation and string manipulation. A lazy alternative to registered and shared memories is using global memory and hope that caching works out.